# To show the center of homothety of the biggest and smallest circle lies in the common tangent over T

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation, homothety, soddy-circles

$c_1$ centered at $A$ passing through $B$.

$BB′$ is a diameter of $c_1$.

$T$ a random point in segment $BB′$.

$c_2$ centered at $B′$ passing through $T$.

$c_3$ centered at $B$ passing through $T$.

$c_4$ tangent externally to $c_2$ and $c_3$ and internally tangent to $c_1$

$F$ is center of $c_4$ and $H,I$ are tangency points.

[image]

It is clear to me that $Z = HI \cap AF$ is the second homothety center of $c_1$ and $c_4$ and I would like to prove that it also lies in that line perpendicular to $AB$ through $T$.

important related result that you probably should know: [Show these three circles share their external common tangent lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781074/show-these-three-circles-share-their-external-common-tangent-lines)

This seems to be a general result about soddy circles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Let common tangent at $T$ meet $AF$ at $Y$ and let perpendicular to $AB$ through $F$ meet $AB$ at $L$. [image] Then we calculate $y=LT$ by Pythagoras theorem:
  $$ B'F^2-B'L^2 = LF^2 =BF^2-BL^2$$
  so $$ (b+c)^2-(b-y)^2 = (2a+b+c)^2-(2a+b+y)^2$$
  and so we get $$y= {ac\over a+b}$$ so $${AY\over FY}  = {AT\over LT} = {a\over y} = {a+b\over c}$$
- On the other hand let $X$ be in $HI\cap AF$.
  [image]
  Homothety $H_1$ at $H$ and coefficient ${b\over c}$ takes $F$ to $B'$ and homothety $H_2$ at $G$ and coefficient ${a+b\over b}$ takes $B'$ to $A$, so composition $H_2\circ H_1$ takes $F$ to $A$ and has center at $FA\cap GH =X$. This composition has coefficent $${a+b\over b}\cdot {b\over c} = {a+b\over c}$$ so $X$ divides $AF$ in the same ratio as $Y$ and thus $X=Y$ and we are done.

Comment: -@Aqua, I request you to please intervene in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609286/782505) question and say whether the downvote on my answer is justified or not. Or mistake did I make?

Comment: @Aqua, do you mean $H_1$ takes $F$ to $B'$ rather than $B$?

Comment: @brainjam Yes, thanks.

Comment: @Aqua, how do we know that $X$ is the center of the composition?

Comment: since it takes F to A it must be on FA and since it is also on line between centers i.e. H and G it lies also on the line HG = line HI @brainjam

Comment: @Aqua, thanks - that explains why $X$ is a fixed point (and thus center) of the composition. Hopefully fInal question: how do we know $HG=HI$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781074/show-these-three-circles-share-their-external-common-tangent-lines @brainjam

Answer (score 0):

The argument in [Aqua's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3798383/1257) can be shortened as follows.  We use the same point names, but here $a,b,c$ are the radii of the circles centered at $A,B',F$ respectively (this changes the meaning of $a$).  Let $LT:TA$ be $x$.

As described in Yiu's [Triangle Geometry, pg 2](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/YIUIntroductionToTriangleGeometry121226.pdf), the internal homothetic center $X$ (aka internal center of similitude) of two circles $O(R),I(r)$ divides the segment $OI$ in the ratio $R:r$.  Thus the internal homothetic point of $F(c),A(a)$ divides $FA$ in the ratio $c:a$.

Using Pythagoras' Theorem as in [Aqua's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3798383/1257) we get

$$
(b+c)^2-(b-x(a-b))^2=(2a=b+c)^2-(2a-b+x(a-b))^2
 $$

Solving for $x$ (using an [online solver](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20%28b%2Bc%29%5E2-%28b-x%28a-b%29%29%5E2%3D%282a-b%2Bc%29%5E2-%282a-b%2Bx%28a-b%29%29%5E2) if we are lazy) we get $x=\dfrac{c}{a}$.  Thus

$$
FY:YA  = LT:TA = x = c:a,
$$

so $Y$ is the internal homothetic center of $c_1,c_4$.